# Selectively install package from centosplus

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, yum

How can I selectively install a package from the `centosplus` repository in CentOS 6.0? If I enable that repo and run a `yum update`, it would install other packages (newer kernels etc.) too. I just need one package from `centosplus`, but I'd like to get everything else from the base repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `includepkgs=` (*I need only these packages*) or `exclude=` (*I don't want these packages*) in centosplus repo file.

More info at

```
man 5 yum.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

`yum --enablerepo=centosplus install packagename` should do this for you.